# Calculate PCA using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, pca

I am new to python programming and would like to ask about the PCA (Principal Component Analysis) in numpy.
I have a dataset containing 2d numpy array. How can I find PCA on this dataset using numpy. What will be the best method?

```
Output of the list:

[[  9.59440303 -30.33995167  -9.56393401 ...,  20.47675724  21.32716639
    4.72543396]
 [  9.51383834 -29.91598995 -15.53265741 ...,  29.3551776   22.27276737
    0.21362916]
 [  9.51410643 -29.76027936 -14.61218821 ...,  26.02439054   4.7944802
   -4.97069797]
 ..., 
 [ 10.18460025 -25.08264383  -8.48524125 ...,  -3.86304594  -7.48117144
    0.49041786]
 [ 10.11421507 -27.23984612  -8.57355611 ...,   1.86266657  -5.25912341
    4.07026804]
 [ 11.86344836 -29.08311293  -6.40004177 ...,   3.81287345  -8.21500311
   18.31793505]]
```

The given data is for example but the actual data contains very long datas which may be corelated. You can use Iris data or some other dummy data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Nils suggested, the easiest solution is to use the PCA class from the scikit-learn package. If for some reason you can't use scikit-learn, the PCA algorithm itself is fairly simple. In the source code of scikit-learn you can find it here:
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/decomposition/pca.py#L408

as a simplified summary:

```
centered_data = data - np.mean(data)
U, S, V = np.linalg.svd(centered_data, full_matrices=False)
components = V
coefficients = np.dot(U, np.diag(S))
```

Comment: it is giving me this error:
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1540, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "speaker-recognition.py", line 40, in calc_mfcc
    coefficients = np.dot(U, np.diag(S))
ValueError: shapes (364,364) and (13,13) not aligned: 364 (dim 1) != 13 (dim 0)

Comment: Use `full_matrices=False` (I changed my answer accordingly)

Answer (score 2):

Using [`sklearn.decomposition.PCA(n_components=2).fit(data)`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html).